# How to filter in CKEditor?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

How are you guys doing?

I am recently doing applying CKEditor to my corp's editor.
It's been great though I've got stuck in some problem.

I expect it to be the best even when we paste other contents from web or Word, but What blocks me doing is something kind of inline style tag, such as 'p style....' since it won't take its style away that my viewer doesn't seem to keep the same form.

I found out that filter.js would be the perfect solution for it. But there doesn't seem to be any way I can handle in my IDE since it doesn't exist.

How can I find a file called 'filter.js' or other plug-in so that I can handle the other way. this is the URL which would be help.

http://docs.ckeditor.com/source/filter.html#CKEDITOR-filter

Thanks.
Do I have to make new file called filter.js so I can edit on my own. 
So confused. Hope to get some nice solution to it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

CKEditor has a robust content filtering system called ACF (Advanced Content Filter). Read more about it here: http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_acf and see the samples here: http://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/acf.html. It's highly flexible so you can customize it to your needs.

Comment: yeah, but What I find hard is where to put these coding.

Comment: would it be working if I put this code in confg.js ??